# Live HTML Previewer on Mac Visual Studio code doesn't work

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code on Mac and installed **Live HTML Previewer extension** as well. but this extension shows neither failure nor displays side window to show live changes.
Any idea?
Am I doing something wrong or this extension isn't being supported by Visual Studio Code editor anymore?

Thanks a lot for your gently feedback!

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't seem to work for me either. It has a bad rating, maybe it is bugged?

Comment: did you try it today or earlier?

Comment: i did it just before i commented. Never used it before this time

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hdg.live-html-previewer&ssr=false#review-details speaks for itself. Maybe [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tht13.html-preview-vscode) is working..

Comment: ohhh, I am not the only guy, who has this problem! then I leave it. Do you guys have any idea, which I can use similar extension?